# Not showing text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm, creating a barista small application with three buttons, not trying to have the text show "one that would be
" until someone clicks one of the three components. I know that I'm close just can't find any references to it
Here is my html:

```
    <div id="app">

    <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>


    <!--template for Barista-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
        <div> one {{order_type}} that would be {{order_value}}</div>
        <button v-on:click="choose('Drip')">Drip</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('Frenchpress')">French Press</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('Aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my Javascript

```
Vue.component("barista-template",{
    template: "#b-template",
    data: function () {
        return{
            user_order:"",
            computer:"",
            outcome:"",
            order_type:"",
            order_value: "",    
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choose: function (order_type) {
            this.order_type = order_type;

            if (this.user_order == "drip") {
                if (this.order_value == "drip") this.order_value = $10;

            }
            if (this.user_order == "frenchpress") {
                // if (this.computerMove == "frenchpress") this.outcome ="French press";

            }
            if (this.user_order == "Aeropress") {
                if (this.computerMove == "Aeropress") this.outcome ="Aeropress";

            }

        }
    }

});

new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data:function () {
        return{
            showing:false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a computed for this, but you can do it in-line too with

`<div v-if="order_type !== ''"> one {{order_type}} that would be {{order_value}}</div>`

computed just makes code more readable

```js
Vue.component("barista-template",{
  template: "#b-template",
  data: function () {
    return{
          order_type:"",
          order_value: "",    
      }
  },
  computed: {
    showText () {
      if(this.order_type === '') return '';
      return 'one ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
    }
  },
  methods: {
      choose: function (order_type) {
          this.order_type = order_type;

          if (this.order_type == "drip") {
              this.order_value = "$10";

          }
          if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
              this.order_value = "$20";
          }
          if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
              this.order_value = "$30";
          }
      }
  }

});

new Vue ({
  el:"#app",
  data:function () {
      return{
          showing:false
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>

<!--template for Barista-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
    <div>{{showText}}</div>
    <button v-on:click="choose('drip')">Drip</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('frenchpress')">French Press</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you what if I want to have more than 1 order value for all three components?

Comment: are you trying to add them up when pressing the button?

Comment: no I'm trying to have  different order_values for all three buttons so if someone pressed Drip it will have a diffirent price then frenchpress

Comment: check the code, I had updated it with the order_values